# How to add an external link under a page in Kentico?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico

We’re using Kentico 11.0.26 with MVC.
I need to add an external link under a page.

In content tree it should look something like this:

- Page A

  - Page A1
  - Page A2
  - https://www.www.google.com/

The problem is that when I click the + button in Pages application, I only see page types, and there is no option to add a link.

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: Make the external link appear in list of child menu items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new content type to represent an external link and put that into your content tree.  This would then also give you options to set additional properties of the link such as target and title rather than just a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use value of page field to store the link and load the value inside of MVC app? Content tree alone does not have capability for this. All nodes have to be pages in one way or the other and plain old link to external domain can not be placed instead of page. To be honest I do not see benefit of having a link inside of content tree even for menu since you have to create menu using document path and not only its name anyway so accessing additional property should not be that much of a problem.